# Show that $\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=-m}^m(-1)^n\frac{1}{z-n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**: Show that $\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=-m}^m(-1)^n\frac{1}{z-n}$.

**Specifically.....**: Ahlfors derives this on page 189/190 of his "Complex Analysis" book.  In it, he uses his derivations for $\pi\cot\pi z$, specifically, $$\pi\cot\pi z=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=-m}^m\frac{1}{z-n}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}$$  I suppose I am wondering if there is maybe a way to derive the question above without the use of $\pi\cot\pi z$?  Maybe using the Laurent Series expansion of $\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}$, but I wasn't getting anything to come out cleanly (maybe I just made a mistake).

Comment: I'm not surprised Laurent series doesn't work, this function has poles everywhere! The maximum radius of convergence for any such series would be $\pi$ (the distance between neighboring poles). The beauty of the expression on the right is that it is not a power series, so notions like "center" and "radius" don't make sense.

Comment: Looks like an application of the [Mittag-Leffler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) to me.

Comment: There might be a way to use whichever technique was used to prove the other identity, since the two identities don't differ too much. (For example, the Herglotz trick works in this case.)

Comment: It's just, as @mrtaurho highlights an application of [Mittag-Lefflet theorem][1] (I was writing this while you posted the comment so I finish) but the proof of this theorem might be heavy

Comment: @BastienTourand Of course, the Mittag-Leffler theorem should only be used if it's already proven; otherwise using the cotagent series is the go-to as there is a derivation, known as *Herglotz Trick*, which (IIRC) doesn't need any heavy machinery at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi z}} =
\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n = -m}^{m}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over z - n}}:\
{\Large ?}}$.

---

With $\ds{m \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 1}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi z}} =
{1 \over z} + {1 \over z}\bracks{{\pi z \over \sin\pars{\pi z}} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over z} + {1 \over z}\bracks{%
\lim_{m \to \ \infty}\sum_{{\Large n\ =\ -m} \atop {\Large n\ \not=\ 0}}^{m}
a_{n}\pars{{1 \over z - n} + {1 \over n}}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{a_{n} \equiv
\mrm{Res}\pars{{\pi z \over \sin\pars{\pi z}} - 1, z = n} =
\lim_{z \to n}
\braces{\pars{z - n}\bracks{{\pi z \over \sin\pars{\pi z}} - 1}} = \pars{-1}^{n}\, n}$.

See [Mittag-Leffler Expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.10.E25).
Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi z}} =
{1 \over z} + {1 \over z}\bracks{%
\lim_{m \to \ \infty}\sum_{{\Large n\ =\ -m} \atop {\Large n\ \not=\ 0}}^{m}
{\pars{-1}^{n}\,z \over z - n}} =
{1 \over z} + 
\lim_{m \to \ \infty}\sum_{{\Large n\ =\ -m} \atop {\Large n\ \not=\ 0}}^{m}
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over z - n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\large\lim_{m \to \ \infty}\sum_{n\ =\ -m}^{m}
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over z - n}} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in the comments this is a typical usage of the [Mittag-Leffler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem). As the same theorem also can be used for deriving the cited cotangent series this is not a fundamentally different approach.

Note, however, that the cotangent series can be derived completely different using the so-called [Herglotz Trick](https://www-m9.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/WS2010/IMCSeminar/Cotangent.pdf), which is an elementary approach using no heavy machinery from complex analysis. The linked PDF only proves the series representation in case of real arguments but if I am not mistaken the result can be easily extended to whole complex plane by continuation as usual. This might be of particular interest if you have not covered Mittag-Leffler yet.

The Laurent series approach fails due to the many singularities of the given function (as noted by *Ninad Munshi*). I am not aware of a different approach than using Mittag-Leffler directly or the Herglotz Trick.