# Did I set up the equation for the Mittag-Leffler theorem correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis, mittag-leffler-function

From [the wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem), it looks like a meromorphic the function is written as $$f(z) = \sum_{a\in E}p_a(z)$$ where $p_a(z)$ is the *principal part* (a Laurent series), $a$ is the place where a singularity occurs and I is the points belonging to some open set where the singularities occur. It looks like in the theorem, it also defines $p_a(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{N_a}\frac{c_{a,n}}{(z-a)^n}$

So let's say I have one of the examples on the page $\cot(z)$, we would have a singularity at the points $z=0$ and $z=n\pi$ and this would occur for all integers $-\infty \le n \le \infty$, so if I were to write this out, I would get:

$$f(z) = \cot(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)} = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N \Big( \sum_{n=1}^{N_a}\frac{c_{n\pi,n}}{(z-n\pi)^n}\Big)$$

I'm assuming that after finding $p_a(z)$ from finding the Laurent series (however that's done, I've never done one myself), the sum ends up becoming: $$f(z) = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{z-n\pi}$$.

Is that correct?

---

Note: Something unusual I noticed in the example for $\cot(z)$ is that despite $\frac{1}{z-n\pi}$ not being even (nor odd), it appears that the infinite sum was simplified by being split and doubled i.e.: $$\sum_{-N}^N a_n = a_0 + 2\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$$.

Comment: I did some digging and it does indeed look like this was set up properly for the most part. I'll need to perform an example to make sure.

Comment: I finished my example. What I have is almost correct, however I tried this for $sin(z)$ and I was supposed to be $$f(z) = \frac{(-1)^n}{z-n\pi}$$. Don't know where the $(-1)^n$ term is coming from

Comment: Mittag-Leffler theorem states that a meromorphic function can be represented as a sum of its main parts at the poles (modulo certain polynomial correction at each pole for a function that has an infinite number of poles) plus an entire function.  $\sin(z)$ is an entire function, so it has __no principal parts__, and the Mittag-Leffler series consists only of $\sin(z)$ itself, so I do not understand where did you get the poles from. You have probably confused poles with zeros or $\sin(z)$ with $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$. I will write a more elaborate answer shortly.

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku Yes my understanding was that the poles existed at singularities which would be at every $\sin(n\pi)$. Also I wrote the solution wrong, it's supposed to be a sum, but it looks like from the wiki page example that it asserts that each singularity occurs at $n\pi$. Anyways, I just now (almost to the minute) that you replied came up with what I think might be the solution for obtaining $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z-n\pi}$$ and was about to write out what I obtained, but I'll let you post what you have first if you've already started writing your own.

Comment: Once again I stress that this is not a series for $\sin(z)$, and $\sin(z)$ can not be meaningfully expressed as a Mittag-Leffler series at all. It looks like the series for $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$, though I need to check. Edit: in fact, [one of the related questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795563/show-that-frac-pi-sin-pi-z-lim-m-to-infty-sum-n-mm-1n-frac1z?rq=1) at the bottom of the page confirms that this is the series for $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ (possibly up to a factor of $\pi$) right in the headline.

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku The answer to the question provided seems to show that you can alter the function into the form they linked [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.10#E25). Which I think is what you said before, you need to add some function on for it to be valid. But I'm guessing this is a case which is an exception to the theorem where it looks like it works on paper, but actually doesn't? Would $\cot(z)$ also fail since it has poles at every $n\pi$?

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku Just as an addition to provide motivation, the entire reason I wanted to find out how to perform this expansion was because it was suggested to me [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4830158/how-to-evaluate-a-series-when-sinh-or-some-other-hyperbolic-trig-function-is-i) that one could expand $\csch(x)$. This is a function which occurs a lot in solutions to PDEs and can make evaluating series solutions a headache

Comment: If you are talking about the Weierstrass product formula, i.e. the fact that $\sin(\pi z)= \pi z \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right)$, yes, that is true, and has an obvious connection to Mittag-Leffler theorem, but that's a different thing: you can decompose certain classes of entire functions into infinite products of monomials which have the same zeros. However, that's a different question from the one you asked. $\cot(z)$ has a meaningful Mittag-Leffler decomposition exactly because it has poles. Kindly check the answer I wrote below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mittag-Leffler theorem (as per Shabat's "Introduction to complex analysis") states the following:

**Theorem (Mittag-Leffler)**

> For every sequence of points $a_{n}\in \mathbb{C}$, such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=\infty$, and for any sequence of functions $g_{n}$ of the form $$g_{n}(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{p_{n}}\frac{c_{-k}^{(n)}}{(z-a_n)^{k}}$$ where $p_n \in \mathbb{N}$, $c_{-k}^{(n)}\in \mathbb{C}$, there exists a meromorphic function $f$ that has poles of degree $p_n$ at each point $a_n$ (and only at these points), and the principal part of the Laurent series of $f$ at each point $a_n$ coincides with $g_n(z)$.

In plain language, it says that for every possible sequence of poles and principal parts there exists a meromorphic function that has exactly these poles and principal parts. Note that this function is not unique: since entire functions (i.e. holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$) have no poles and principal parts in $\mathbb{C}$, if $f(z)$ is a function the existence of which is stated by Mittag-Leffler theorem, then for any entire $h(z)$ $f(z)+h(z)$ has the same poles and principal parts, and thus verifies the theorem. Mittag-Leffler theorem has a corollary which allows one to express an arbitrary meromorphic function in terms of its principal parts.

**Corollary**

> Every meromorphic function $f(z)$ can be represented as a sum $$f(z)=h(z)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(g_{n}(z)-P_n(z))$$ which converges uniformly at any compact not including the poles of $f(z)$, where $g_{n}(z)$ are principal parts of $f(z)$ at poles $z_{n}$, $h(z)$ is some entire function, and $P_n(z)$ are some polynomials (these polynomials are decompositions of the corresponding principal parts in Taylor series around zero up to a sufficiently high term, see below).

Several remarks about this corollary.

1. If a function $f(z)$ has only a finite number of poles, $f(z)-\sum_{n}g_{n}(z)$ is well-defined and is an entire function, so in the case of a meromorphic function with a finite number of poles there is no need for correction polynomials. Hence, for a meromorphic function $f(z)$ with a finite number of poles,
   $$f(z)=h(z)+\sum_{n=1}^{N}g_{n}(z)$$
   where $h(z)$ is an entire function, and $g_{n}(z)$ are principal parts of $f(z)$.
   In particular, any rational function can be decomposed into a polynomial (the entire part) and principal parts (partial fraction decomposition).
2. In the case of an infinite number of poles we need the polynomials $P_n(z)$, because otherwise the series may not converge. These polynomials, as was mentioned before, are, in general, obtained in the following way: for each principal part $g_{n}(z)$ at the point $z_{n}$, we decompose it in the Taylor series $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{d^n}{dz^n}g_{n}(z)\Bigg|_{z=0} \cdot \frac{z^k}{k!}$$
   around zero. We can do that, because $g_{n}(z)$ has a single pole at $z_n$, hence, the radius of convergence of its Taylor series around zero is $|z_n|$. We then truncate the Taylor series for $g_{n}(z)$ around such term that inside the circle $|z|\le |z_{n}|$ $\left|g_{n}(z)-\sum_{k=0}^{N(n)}\frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!}z^{k} \right|$ is sufficiently small, for instance, less than $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. This is possible because the Taylor series of a function holomorphic at a certain domain converges uniformly inside this domain, and $g_{n}(z)$ is holomorphic in the disk $|z|<|z_{n}|$. Then the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(g_{n}-P_{n}(z))$ converges uniformly on every compact in $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{z_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. The choice of truncation number is not unique thanks to the freedom of choice of the entire function $h(z)$.
3. In the proof of the Mittag-Leffler theorem we use a system of expanding contours around zero, the interior of which in the limit covers the whole complex plane and which have a "well-behaved" boundary (means it does not become a fractal in the limit). The series of principal parts, in fact, must be summed in the same order the corresponding poles were covered by the contours, because the series does not have to converge absolutely. In the explanation above that system was just the sequence of circles $|z|=|z_n|$, but we may choose a different system, if we make the series converge uniformly inside each contour. If $f(z)$ behaves on these contours in a nice way, that allows us to simplify the Mittag-Leffler series.

For instance, if $f(z)=o(1)$ at a certain system of such expanding contours (decresases at infinity), then, by Liouville's theorem, the entire part of $f(z)$ is zero (because all entire functions are either constants or grow in absolute value at infinity, and the maximum of modulus is always reached at the boundary of each domain), so the Mittag-Leffler series becomes the sum of principal parts:
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_{n}(z)$$
Again note that the principal parts must be summed in order they appear inside an expanding sequence of contours.

If $f(z)$ grows as a polynomial $|z^p|$ on a certain system of contours, then we can represent
$$f(z)=f^{[p-1]}(z)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(g_{n}(z)-g_{n}^{[p-1]}(z))$$
where the notation $f(z)^{[k]}(z)$ denotes the Taylor series for $f(z)$ at zero, truncated at the $k$-th term (the term with $z^{k}$ is included, the next one is not).

As an example, consider the function $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$. It has a pole at zero, $1/\sin(z) \approx 1/z$ around zero, so, for the reasoning behind the theorem to work, we have to first subtract $\frac{1}{z}$, which is the principal part at 0. For the new function $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{z}$, which has poles at the points $\pm  \pi k$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$, we can choose the sequence of square contours $C_{n}$ which are squares with the side length $2\pi n + 1$ centered at zero and passing through the real line vertically at points $\pm \pi(n + \frac{1}{2})$. At these points $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{z}$ has values $1+\frac{\pm 1}{\pi k}$, and outside the real axis the absolute value decreases as $1/|z|$, since $1/|\sin(z)|$ decays exponentially outside the real axis. So our function is $o(z^{1})$ at the chosen contours, and we can write down decomposition:
$$\frac{1}{\sin z}-\frac{1}{z}=\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{\sin z}-\frac{1}{z}\right)(0)}_{\text{The 1-1=0-th term of the Taylor decomposition}} = 0$$ $$ + \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left(\text{Res}_{z=\pi n}  \left(\frac{1}{\sin(z)} -\frac{1}{z}\right) \frac{1}{z-\pi n} + \text{Res}_{z= -\pi n}\left(\frac{1}{\sin(z)} - \frac{1}{z} \right) \frac{1}{z+\pi n}\right)$$

where we used the fact that zeros of entire function $f(z)$ are exactly the poles of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ of the same degree (or just the $2\pi k$-translational invariance of $\sin(z)$) to guess the placement and degree of the poles. Note also that the polynomials corresponding to principal parts are of degree 0, hence, they are the zeroth terms of Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1 \pm \pi k z}$ around zero, and cancel out for each pair $\pm k$. Now, let us calculate the residues:
$$\text{Res}_{z=\pm \pi n} \frac{1}{\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{z}=\lim_{z\to \pm \pi n}(z- \mp \pi n)\left( \frac{1}{\sin(z)} - \frac{1}{z} \right)=(-1)^{n}$$
The fact that the values of the residue alternate can be seen from L'Hopital's rule and the fact that sine is periodic, hence it increases at one zero and decreases at the next, with the value of derivative $\pm 1$, while $(z-\pi k)$ always has derivative $1$ at $\pi k$. And so we obtain
$$\frac{1}{\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{z}=\sum_{k=-\infty, k \ne 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(1-\pi k z)}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sin(z)}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(1-\pi k z)}$$

Try to obtain the Mittag-Leffler decomposition for $\cot(z)$ as an exercise. Hint: it looks almost the same, and you can use the same system of contours.

Comment: I finally circled back to this question and am working on finding a Mittag-Leffler expansion for $f(z) = \frac{1}{\cos(z)}$. You mentioned that some function needs to be incorporated, and for the $\csc(z)$ example, $\frac{1}{z}$ was used because they approximately shared a pole. Could I say that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow \pi/2} \frac{1}{\cos(z)} \approx \lim_{z\rightarrow \pi/2}\frac{1}{z-\pi/2}$$ and therefore use $$\frac{1}{\cos(z)}-\frac{1}{z-n\pi}$$?

Comment: Also you said that $\frac{1}{z}$ is the principal part of \frac{1}{\sin(z)} centered at pole $a = 0$. So just to clarify we *can* have a Laurent series of $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$? I might have misinterpreted your previous messages, or the principal part (the negative power part of the Laurent series) is a different case.

Comment: You don't need to subtract any principal parts in the case of $\frac{1}{\cos(z)}$, because $\cos(z)$ has no poles at zero. We need the function we work with to be analytic in the neighborhood of zero, because we expand principal parts in Taylor series in the neighborhood of zero, and a pole at zero prevents that.

Comment: The Laurent series of a function is defined __in a neighborhood of a given point__ (or, rather, in an annulus surrounding the point). The Mittag-Leffler series is defined __globally__.

Comment: I finally have a bit better grasp of the answer (sorry I'm a bit slow), so I have the Principal part would give $$g_1(z) = \frac{1}{cos(z)} = ...+\frac{0}{(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^2} - \frac{1}{z-\frac{\pi}{2}} = -\frac{1}{z-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$. This would be our $g_n(z)$ at n = 1, right? I'm assuming the first formula in your answer was the formula for the principal part.

Comment: And the Mittag-Leffler's expansion is going to be the sum over all the principal parts: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(z)$$ So if we were to write the principal part to globally include all poles at $\frac{2n-1}{2}\pi$ we would have the principal all the principal parts $$g_n(z) = ... -\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{z-\frac{2n-1}{2}\pi}  = -\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{z-\frac{2n-1}{2}\pi}\ \ n\in \mathbb{N}$$ or it would be $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ I guess according to the wiki.

Comment: Yep, sorry, haven't noticed you'd specified the point you were calculating the principal part at after the calculation, however, this specification is still implicit: $n=1$ could refer to the first pole to the right of zero or to the first pole to the left of zero. If you meant the pole at $z=\pi/2$, then yes, this seems right.

Comment: To your second comment: if $f(z)$ is entire (i.e. analytic on the whole complex plane), then the poles of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ are exactly the zeroes of $f(z)$, and have the same degree as the degree of the zeroes. $\cos(z)$ is entire, because it is a sum of two exponents, the exponent is entire, and a finite sum of entire functions is entire. Think where $\cos(z)$ has zeroes, and you will easily understand where $\frac{1}{\cos(z)}$ has poles. And at each pole you have a principal part.

Comment: Okay! Well then I think I should have it. Taking the sum would yield: $$f(z) = \frac{1}{\cos(z)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z-(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{z-((-n)+1/2)\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{z-(n+1/2)\pi}+\frac{-1}{z-\pi/2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\Big(\frac{1}{z-(n+1/2)\pi} + \frac{1}{z+((-n)+1/2)\pi}\Big) - \frac{1}{z-\pi/2}$$ and then I need to simplify it from there.

Comment: Sadly I could not verify the exact result from the wiki as it appears to use $$\frac{1}{((n+1/2)\pi+z)}$$ for the summation over $-\infty$ to $-1$ and also appears to truncate off the term at $n=0$. My assumption is that instead of replacing $n$ with $(-n)$ to make the summation interval positive, they instead replaced $n+1/2$ with $-(n+1/2)$ and as for the term at $n=0$, I'm not sure. Have you derived this result before? It should end up as $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{((n+1/2)\pi-z)((n+1/2)\pi+z)}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2-z^2}$$

Comment: No, I have not calculated this specific series before, but you can just substitute $z\to z + \pi/2$ into the series for $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ to obtain the series for $\frac{1}{\cos(z)}$. What result from the wiki are you referring to?

Comment: The result is [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem#Pole_expansions_of_meromorphic_functions) for example $\sec(z)$. The final form is on the one I'm referencing. For Mittag-Leffler's expansion, we want the sum to start at $n=0$ not all integer values of $n$, so we make some modifications to the sum which results in the form I showed earlier.

Comment: Just group terms of the form $1/(z-a)+1/(z+a)$, reduce them to the common denominator and represent $(z-a)(z+a)$ as $z^2-a^2$ in the denominator

Comment: Oh no I completely understand the process for how it should be obtained. Under ideal circumstances plugging in for $\csc(z+\pi/2)$ to get $\sec(z)$ would yield the form $\frac{1}{z-a}+\frac{1}{z-a}$ and then we can easily combine and simplify. The issue is we don't actually have that form which looks to be exactly how it would be obtained on the wiki page. The problem is that instead when we plug this in we get $$\frac{1}{z+\pi/2 - a} + \frac{1}{z+\pi/2 + a}$$ and we could absorb the $\pi/2$ terms into the constants such that $-b = \pi/2-a$, $c = \pi/2 +a$

Comment: Or I guess we could instead do $z+\pi/2 = k$ and we would have $$\frac{1}{k-a}+\frac{1}{k+a}$$ and *that* would let us simplify it down. Maybe I can try that and then replace k in the final result. I'll try that now!

Comment: Sadly this did not work, I ended up with $$\csc(z+\pi/2)=\frac{1}{k}+2k\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \Big(\frac{2k}{k^2-a^2}\Big) = \frac{1}{z+\pi/2}+4(z+\pi/2)^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \Big(\frac{(-1)^n}{(z+\pi/2)^2-(n\pi)^2}\Big)$$. I might need to post a separate question as maybe someone has derived this expansion and might have some insights. However, thank you for guiding me through a basic understanding of how to set these up. It'll will definitely helped me more than reading through a few wiki pages and YT videos to learn about them! Once I have that, I'll work through $\cot(z)$ and post it here