# Deduce that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\pi\coth\pi-1)\quad$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

I am having problems showing that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\pi\coth\pi-1)\quad $$
Here's my attept to this point:
I tried to express each term using a partial fraction decomposition: $\frac1{1+ni}$ and $\frac1{1-ni}$. And I've been suggested from there that partial fractions can be expressed in terms of hyperbolic trigonometric functions. But i am stuck at this point. How to write a solution for this sum?

Comment: Do you have to perform the summation explicitly, using no other methods? Because this is the Mittag-Leffler series for $\coth$, and the standard way to arrive to this result is to use the Mittag-Leffler theorem and the calculus of residues. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4830791/did-i-set-up-the-equation-for-the-mittag-leffler-theorem-correctly/4832889#4832889) you can find my answer explaining the procedure.